# Accessing Multiple array with objects php

Tags: php, arrays

Ok guys, so I want to know what the key is of the second value so that I can get said value.
So I want to be able to get the "5" or "4" from newsId. So it will be $array[0] to access the first array but what are the keys to access just the "5"??

This is the vardump

```
array(5) { [0]=> object(NewsArticleBase)#6 (7) 
{ ["newsId:private"]=> string(1) "5" ["newsTitle:private"]=> string(41) "XCR'14 Round 5 Sandown Road Relay Champs!" ["newsPreview:private"]=> string(243) " Teams compete on the fast Sandown course for the honour of the Victorian Road Relay Championship.Two laps of the motor racing circuit make for 6.2km legs for open and overage competitors, whilst the juniors race over one lap of 3.1km." ["newsDisplayPicture:private"]=> string(57) "images/10464246_236382816571109_6852705680507428565_n.jpg" ["newsContent:private"]=> string(6) "asdsad" ["newsCategories:private"]=> string(21) "Long Distance Running" ["newsSubmissionDate:private"]=> string(19) "2014-07-24 11:33:32" } 
[1]=> object(NewsArticleBase)#7 (7) 
{ ["newsId:private"]=> string(1) "4" ["newsTitle:private"]=> string(52) "XCR'14 Round 4 Everyones favourite course Bundoora!!" ["newsPreview:private"]=> string(402) "Selection Trial for the Australian Cross Country Championships This bumper day of cross country racing incorporates the All Schools Cross Country Championships and also serves as the selection trial for the Australian Cross Country Championships. The open and overage men’s race covers 12km of the gruelling slopes of Bundoora Park, while the women’s race covers 8km. Juniors race over 3km, 4km or 6km." ["newsDisplayPicture:private"]=> string(22) "images/displaypicture2" ["newsContent:private"]=> string(8) "asdgfdsg" ["newsCategories:private"]=> string(21) "Long Distance Running" ["newsSubmissionDate:private"]=> string(19) "2014-07-24 11:32:09" }
```

Comment: It'd just be `array[1]` ?

Comment: Nope, that'd be to the second value. I've shortened what the actual code is, just think that there are going to be many objects inside this array, it's a multidimensional, and I'm wanting to know how to get inside the 2nd and/or 3rd key to get that value.

Comment: Then you need to provide that sample data for us to work with.

Comment: Done, refresh the page. It's a multi-dimensional array with an object. I made it shorter for readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `var_dump`, keys are listed as `[key] => type(variable){ value }`

So

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> object(NewsArticleBase)#6 (7) { ["newsId:private"]=> string(1) "2" }
    [1]=> object(NewsArticleBase)#7 (7) { ["newsId:private"]=> string(1) "1" }
}
```

You have `array[0]` and `array[1]`

Now, if the properties were `public` you could just do `array[0]->property` but, in your case, they're `private`. So you would need a method (like a `getVar()`) that could access it and return the value.